# How to suppress the "For input string: " in NumberFormatException.getMessage()?

Tags: java

Below code

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt("foo");
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("Invalid number: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

prints

```
Invalid number: For input string: "foo"
```

I wish to only receive the `"foo"`, so my message would be

```
Invalid number: "foo"
```

I have tried the available APIs, but they all include the `"For input string: "` in the message. I could parse it out, or extend the NumberFormatException, but this is an overkill (and ugly). Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.err.println("Invalid number: " + e.getMessage().replaceAll("For input string: ", ""));
```

This Only Relies on standard Java API.

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
    .substringAfter(e.getMessage(), "For input string: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the number alone since `NumberFormatException` doesn't have a field for this information.

Write your own helper method. In the method, catch the exception and throw your own. That way, you can total control over the message,

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "foo";
try {
    Integer.parseInt(s);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    //log the e here to your file log or wherever you want
    System.err.println("Invalid number: " + s);
}
```

Updated after @Arkadiy 's correction.

Comment: `s` is not visible from catch

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a more meaningful exception text, you'll need to catch the original exception and throw your own:

```
int parseInt(String str) {

    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid number: " + str);
    }
}
```

Not that I'd advise such a thing.